# Inclusion-Exclusion Principle - Confused

Tags: combinatorics

What is the probability that a 9-card hand has at least one 4 of a kind?

I already know the answer is 13 × C(48,5) − C(13,2) × 44, but don't know the steps to get there

Answer (score 0):

The inclusion-exclusion applied here is to calculate the chance of having a four-of-a-kind hand in the obvious way:

$\binom {48}{5}$ is the ways of having a particular rank four-of-a-kind, so multiply by $13$ and then subtract off the double-counted cases where there are two different four-of-a-kinds in the hand, $\binom {13}{2}\binom {44}{1}$

That's the number of options: $13 \binom {48}{5} - \binom {13}{2}\binom {44}{1}$; to get probability you then need to divide that count by all different hands, $\binom{52}{9}$.